# Downgrade Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I`ve installed Xamarin (Xamarin studio, Xamarin.Android) But there are some problems with building even the simpliest project(just create new project->Build->Get an error).

After some googling I found that I`m not the only one experiencing such problems.
The only solution I found is to revert to an earlier version of Xamarin.Android. But how do I do this? Can anyone help, please?

Current version of Xamarin.Android is 4.8.0

Desired version to rollback to is 4.6.6

Comment: Ever considered asking their own tech support?

Comment: I don`t have registered account there. I`m using free trial for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've talked to Xamarin about downgrading. It's not straight-forward. You will need to uninstall everything from Add and Remove Programs and then re-install directly from the following .msi's:

1. JDK 1.6: http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/MonoForAndroid/jdk-6u39-windows-i586.exe
2. Android SDK: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r22-windows.exe
3. GTK#: http://download.xamarin.com/GTKforWindows/Windows/gtk-sharp-2.12.21.msi
4. Xamarin Studio: http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-4.0.8.msi
5. Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio: http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.6.08007.msi
6. Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio: http://download.xamarin.com/MonoTouchforVisualStudio/Windows/mtvs-1.1.200.0.msi

Comment: can I just uninstall Xamarin.Android and download->install Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio from the 5th step?

Comment: I don't know, this is just what they told me.

Answer (score 3):

I downgraded monodroid multiple times because of issues with performance. I did not have to uninstall and re-install everything.

1. Control Panel > Programs and Features > Uninstall Xamarin.Android.#.#.####
2. Download msi http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.6.08007.msi
3. Install

Comment: I have tried this at first. But unfortunately the higher version of Xamarin studio didn`t want to work with previous version of monodroid =/ Don`t know why. So I had to downgrade Xamarin studio as well. And only then it worked for me.

Comment: Was it studio did not want to work or the version of Xamarin.Android gave an appt.exe not found? That error is from android sdk build tools 17+ moving the appt.exe file around.

Comment: Xamarin studio wa the one to refuse working with older version of monodriod

Answer (score 0):

easiest way of doing is as described [here](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1699777-how-do-i-downgrade-to-an-older-version-)

Download links
Links for the recent individual installer packages can be found on https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads.

[image]

In most cases, uninstalling is not even neccessary. just download the version you want to install and it will handle uninstall-install together.