# Downgrade Xamarin.Android 4.14

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've installed Xamarin.Android 4.16 but I have a bug with date and time in this version. So I want to rollback to Xamarin.Android 4.14.

I searched the version 4.14 of Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio, but I can't find it.
Does somebody know the link to access to this version ?

I saw this post : [Downgrade Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850141/downgrade-xamarin-android) and I tried to change the link of the .msi with my version number but I can't find it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you update via Nuget?

Comment: I'm not sure which library you are looking at because I only have Mono.Android or Xamarin.Support.Android.. But you should find this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/) helpful

Comment: I update when Xamarin said to me that a new version was available, Not via Nuget. I search something like that : http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.6.08007.msi

Answer (score 0):

You can get several previous versions right from your Xamarin's account. Go to https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads and select View all versions. Choose what you want. It may happen that required version is not there. Then, just contact support and tell them what version you need (or approximate date/month of your required version if you do not know the number).

Comment: I was hoping there were an another solution because my chief has to do this, I can't do this by myself. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Contact support if you cannot login to the account. There is nothing special in providing the link to the build, i believe, because the licensing process is done via Internet.