# Install specific old version of Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

**TL;DR** Is there a way to find the specific Xamarin.Android download link for a specific version mentioned in the [release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_4/xamarin.android_4.20/)?

I would like to patch an app that was build using Xamarin.Android v4.20.0.34 so I need to downgrade my toolset (In future I'll take a snapshot of my build agent VM)

I can find the [4.20 release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_4/xamarin.android_4.20/) but the downloads referred to in the KB article [How do I downgrade to an older version of Xamarin?](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1699777-how-do-i-downgrade-to-an-older-version-) are all version 3.11.xxxx:

[image: Download options]

I think that when I had this issue before, based on the stack answer to [Downgrade Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18901213/270155) I managed to guess the URL for the download I required.

Is there a way to find the specific Xamarin.Android download for a specific version mentioned in the [release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_4/xamarin.android_4.20/)?

**Edit**

Is there an unofficial list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (Xamarin) do not list the unsupported versions of Xamarin tools in the store page.

However, you can email hello@xamarin.com or support email to get installers for old versions

Comment: Thanks. I will PM. Is there an unofficial list?

Comment: No, we maintain list internally. And old installers will be given on demand

Comment: For the record, I received a download link from Xamarin support (enterprise) in under 25 mins - along with notes about compatibility (even in the UK)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below url to download specific versions of Xamarin Android.
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android#downloads

Comment: How do you install them if you already have Visual studio ? I get an error saying "This extension is already installed to all applicable products".

Comment: If you are using Mac, go to /Library/Frameworks/ and delete Xamarin.Android.framework. This is what Visual Studio installs as a package. You can install all the components individually as well, but a bit tedious.

Comment: I am using Windows, thanks though. I've "Solved " my problem by installing VS 2017 which comes with an older version of the tools than 2019.